# lxml for Python 2.5.6, osx 10.7.3

Tags: python, macos, lxml

```
python --version
Python 2.5.6
OS X 10.7.3
```

I want to install lxml but cant find successful way for me
tried

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install --install-option="--libxml2-version=2.7.8" lxml
```

using brew etc.

I have no idea what is wrong

My errors:

```
threads.c: In function 'xmlCleanupThreads':
threads.c:918: error: expected expression before '{' token
make[2]: *** [threads.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 10, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c12dev-r85381', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
mkvirtualenv lxml
pip install --no-install --build-dir="./build" lxml
cd build/lxml/
python setup.py build --static-deps --libxml2-version=2.7.8 --libxslt-version=1.1.27
cd -
pip install --no-download --build-dir="./build" lxml
```

And this:

```
pip install \
    --install-option="--static-deps" \
    --install-option="--libxml2-version=2.7.8" \
    --install-option="--libxslt-version=1.1.27" \
    lxml
```

Usually I just install with `pip install lxml`, had no problems so far.